# Rich text content to excel export

Tags: c#, excel, richtextbox, export-to-excel

I have a rich text content to database

```
<p>
<strong>Hi This </strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">is a sample
</span> 
example
<span style="text-decoration: underline;"> on how thing will be working</span>
<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">from here</span> 
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">on in the new project</span>
</p>
```

After fetching it from database, how to export to excel so that the output looks like

**Hi This** is a sample
     
    example
     on how thing will be working
    from here 
    *on in the new project*

Answer (score 1):

Open your `.rtf` file with notepad.

Replace all `<p>` with nothing

Replace all `</p>` with `;`

Save as `.csv`

Open in excel